# Ошибка jquery 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Есть магазин на wordpress+woocommerce и его файле `add-to-cart.js` строчка кода в самом верху:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

// wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined' )
    return false;
});
```

Почему у меня в консоли постоянно валится jquery ошибка `/undefined 404 (Not Found)` и при этом скрипт продолжает работу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка `/undefined 404 (Not Found)` появляется потому, что где-то происходит AJAX запрос к URL, который строится динамически на основании неопределенной переменной. **Очевидно**, что проблема не в указанном куске кода.

Попробуйте определить, где в вашей системе происходят AJAX запросы (и динамические запросы на подключение скриптов) и посмотрите на используемые адреса и логику их генерации.